# VS code pylint errors and format not working

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint, python-black

Here is the code from test python file with errors:

```
asdf = "test"

print(asdf)


my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]

# expected on save
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for num in my_list:
  print(num)

# Expected on save (does not format)
# print(num)

# if i manully indent to 2 spaces it gives me this error:
#   "Bad indentation. Found 2 spaces, expected 4"
```

Here is the errors I'm getting

[image]

Here is the pip freeze command screenshot:

[image]

Here is my VS code user setting:
[image]

I am not sure why I am getting those error and why is it not formatting.

Comment: try to follow the [pep8 style guideline](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for your code

Comment: also please avoid sharing codes as screenshots as it won't help others reproduce what your're facing and help easily (copy&paste codes in your question with proper formatting instead). [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

These are Convention errors, not functional ones. It means that your code does not follows a certain coding convention. In Pylint it is [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Error Explanations from wiki-dot:

1. [valid-name](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:c0103)
2. [missing-final-newline](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:c0304)